# What if $1/0$ was defined in the limit definition for $f(x)=1/x$

Tags: limits, derivatives

I know the difference quotient is $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}}{h}$ and one would multiply by the denoinators and would eventually get $-\frac{1}{x^2}$ but what would happen if $1/0$ was defined?

Usually the steps would be something like this:
\begin{align*}
& \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}}{h} \\
= & \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{x}{x(x+h)}-\frac{x+h}{x(x+h)}}{h} \\
= & \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{x-x-h}{x(x+h)}}{h} \\
= & \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{-h}{x(x+h)}}{h} \\
= & \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-h}{x(x+h)h} \\
= & \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-1}{x(x+h)} \\
= & \ -\frac{1}{x^2}
\end{align*}

**But if $\frac{1}{0}$ was somehow defined, then what step would be inapplicable if $x=0$?**

My first idea was to let $\frac{1}{0}=a$ and see what happens:
\begin{align*}
& \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-a}{h} \\
= & \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{a(x+h)}{x+h}}{h} \\
= & \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1-a(x+h)}{x+h}}{h} \\
= & \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1-ax-ah}{(x+h)h} \\
\end{align*}
But I'm not sure how to carry on, or really what I'm doing overall since the question I'm working on is purposely something that doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can create a token called $\infty$ and say that $1/x$ converges to it but if you set some $a=1/0$ you have to be careful not to allow $a0=1$ or you get $1=0$ and you're running into serious problems. You can also define an $-\infty$ so that $1/x$ approaches $\infty$ on the right and $-\infty$ on the left. You may also be interested in the one-point compactification of the reals.

Comment: All of the steps of the original argument are invalid when $x=0$ because they all include expressions with $x$ as a factor in the denominator. You could define $a=1/x$, rewrite all fractions of the form $\frac A{xB}$ as $\frac{aA}B$, and proceed to get $-a^2$ as the limit, but this would still only be valid when $x\ne0$.